# Error message 'AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Transpose'' when generating a word cloud

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

I am trying to generate a word cloud from a pandas column.

#text I want to create word cloud with

`text = " ".join(review for review in df.Column.astype(str))`

That runs fine. However when I run:

`wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords).generate(text)`

I receive the following error:

````
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24400/883004456.py in <module>
----> 1 wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords).generate(text)

~\.conda\envs\jupyterlab\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate(self, text)
    630         self
    631         """
--> 632         return self.generate_from_text(text)
    633 
    634     def _check_generated(self):

~\.conda\envs\jupyterlab\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate_from_text(self, text)
    612         """
    613         words = self.process_text(text)
--> 614         self.generate_from_frequencies(words)
    615         return self
    616 

~\.conda\envs\jupyterlab\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies, max_font_size)
    444                 font_size = self.height
    445             else:
--> 446                 self.generate_from_frequencies(dict(frequencies[:2]),
    447                                                max_font_size=self.height)
    448                 # find font sizes

~\.conda\envs\jupyterlab\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies, max_font_size)
    499                     font, orientation=orientation)
    500                 # get size of resulting text
--> 501                 box_size = draw.textsize(word, font=transposed_font)
    502                 # find possible places using integral image:
    503                 result = occupancy.sample_position(box_size[1] + self.margin,

~\.conda\envs\jupyterlab\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py in textsize(self, text, font, spacing, direction, features, language, stroke_width)
    581         if font is None:
    582             font = self.getfont()
--> 583         return font.getsize(text, direction, features, language, stroke_width)
    584 
    585     def multiline_textsize(

~\.conda\envs\jupyterlab\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in getsize(self, text, *args, **kwargs)
    794     def getsize(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
    795         w, h = self.font.getsize(text)
--> 796         if self.orientation in (Image.Transpose.ROTATE_90, Image.Transpose.ROTATE_270):
    797             return h, w
    798         return w, h

~\.conda\envs\jupyterlab\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in __getattr__(name)
     63             stacklevel=2,
     64         )
---> 65         return categories[name]
     66     elif name in ("NEAREST", "NONE"):
     67         warnings.warn(

AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Transpose'```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason

The `worldcloud` module doesn't specify the version of Pillow. In consideration of compatibility with `worldcloud`, you'd better stick with Pillow 8.4.0.

`PIL.Image.Transpose` is not available until Pillow `9.1.0`.

- [Deprecation of Image.ROTATE_90](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/9.1.0.html#constants)

#### Caveat

According to the traceback, it seems the Pillow installation on your machine is **broken**:

- `PIL\ImageFont.py` indicated usage of `Image.Transpose.ROTATE_90`, which means this part of Pillow is from after 9.1.0
- while `PIL\Image.py` raised exc `Image.Transpose`, indicating this part of source file is from Pillow < 9.1.0

Please, please, please. **Don't mix use `pip install` and `conda install`.** Remove your conda environment `jupyterlab` and re-create it. But this time, only install Python packages with one tool: `pip` or `conda`, not both of them.

#### Extended Reading

- [Understanding Conda and Pip](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-conda-and-pip)
- [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment)